# Image set compression

Tags: files, images, compression

Is there a good open source (not exclusive to Linux) for compression of a set of similar images? I have thousands of documents scanned but I do not access them often.

The documents are forms, with little changes (the values, and sometimes the font, and so). I found a lot of papers about this, but neither one app. We use both Windows and Linux, so a cross-platform would be nice.

Comment: If only a few thousand documents is giving you trouble, then probably they're several tens of MB each and you can save a lot by compressing them individually using a more effective/aggressive compression algorithm. An A4 page with mostly text on uniform background should compress to under 200k for acceptable printing quality at 300dpi with JPEG. For monochrome, you can get down to under 50k average for 1-bit depth PNG.

Comment: The documents are color (signature, rubber stamp, watermark, backgrounds are in color) in 600dpi, I don't wanna loose more quality than I've already lost with JPEG compression.Even with paq8o and with djvu

Comment: The documents are color (signature, rubber stamp, watermark, backgrounds are in color) in 600dpi, I don't wanna lose more quality than I've already lost with JPEG compression. And I wanna store it loseless and store more than thousands documents.

Even with paq8o and djvu it's too heavy, I got 0.5-1 MB for A4 color and it get too slow.

Comment: To test if that approach is worthwhile, you could try and make a movie (h264/theora/vp8...) with one page per frame and see if you gain anything.